Construct triangle given intersection of altitudes with circumcircle

Problem: Construct a triangle given intersection of altitudes with circumcircle

I came up with a construction, but I need help proving that it is indeed correct.
Construction:
Let the intersection of the altitudes with the circumcircle be $D, E, F$.
Using these, construct the circumcircle $\Gamma$ with centre $O$ and radius $r$
Construct circles $C_D, C_E, C_F$ with centres $D, E, F$ and radius $r$
Clearly, the circles have a common intersection $O$
From $O$, construct the radical axes of $C_D$ and $C_E$, $C_E$ and $C_F$,  $C_D$ and $C_F$, and let their intersections with the circle $\Gamma$ be $A, B, C$
My claim is that $\triangle{ABC}$ is the required triangle.

Now, I need to prove that $AD \perp BC$ to complete the proof (without loss of generality)
An observation I made was that $A, B, C$ lie on the perpendicular bisectors of $\triangle{DEF}$ by radical axis. I am unable to proceed. Any help would be nice.
Also can someone comment on this interesting fact that the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of $DEF$ with the circumcircle of $ABC$ is in fact $ABC$. It seems like the operations of taking the intersection of the altitudes, and the intersections of the perpendicular bisectors are like inverses! Is there a reason behind this?


We apply these facts:
1-The incenter of triangle DEF is the orthocenter of triangle ABC.
2- The circles passing the orthocenter of ABC and each two vertexes of it have equal diameter with circumcircle of ABC.
3- The feet of altitudes on the sides of ABC are the mid point of segments HD, HE and HF.
So to construct the triangle:
1- we find the incenter of DEF.
2- Find the midpoint of HD, HE and HF.
3-Draw perpendiculars of HD, HE and HF at midpoint L, K and G respectively. They intersects the circumcircle of ABC at (A and C), (A and B) and (A and C) respectively. ABC is the required triangle.
Update: Answering your comment, the second fact, this is a known theorem , you can see it in wiki. I mention it because I wanted to say(but I missed) that the centers of these three circles make a triangle congruent to required triangle . That is with given points D,E and F we can construct two equal triangles , one inside the circumcircle, other center on H equal radius with circumcircle.

"2- The circles passing the orthocenter of ABC and each two vertexes of it have equal diameter with circumcircle of ABC."
Can you explain this a bit better? Is there a proof you can link. Also, I don't think you have used that fact anywhere in the problem?

@Illusioner_, I added some more data. Fact 2 is a well known theorem you see in wiki or modern geometry text books. Please see the edited answer with new figure.

"An observation I made was that ,, lie on the perpendicular bisectors of △ by radical axis." You are very close to the solution. But you could have skipped most of the construct too with what you realized:
Suppose we constructed the qualifying triangle. Note that the complement of angle $C$ subtends two congruent arcs about $C$. So just mark the midpoint of arcs between the $3$ points you are given, that is the desired triangle.


Thank you, that would have indeed been a faster construction, but I guess the intermediate step was required to gain the intuition
